# react hook form props type - typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm having reusable input component and it's used in multiple forms ,so I need it to be a controlled input but I don't know **how to type errors props** as a generic type .

**I need to type errors prop not error**
I did search and no satisfied results

Input.tsx

```
interface Props<T  extends FieldValues> extends UseControllerProps<T> {
  **errors: ???**    //I tried FieldErrors<T>  //not work
  name: Path<T>;
  control: Control<T>;

 //...
    
}
const Input = <T extends FieldValues>({defaultValue,placeholder,
  returnKeyType,readOnly,secureTextEntry,keyboardType,maxLength,leftIcon,rightIcon,onPress,
  testID,name, control, error 
  }:Props<T>) => {
    const dimensions= useWindowDimensions();
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState<boolean>(false)
    return (
      <View>
      <Controller 
      control={control}   
      name={name }
      render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => 
      <TextInput 
      onChangeText={(value: any) => onChange(value) }
        onFocus={()=>{setIsFocused(true)}}
        onBlur={()=>{setIsFocused(false)}}
        style={[styles.input]}
        //underlineStyle={{borderBottomWidth:1,borderColor:COLORS.primary}}
        theme={{colors: {primary:isFocused? COLORS.primary:COLORS.medgray, }}}
        //onChange={(value) => setName(value)}
        left={<TextInput.Icon icon={()=>leftIcon} 
                style={styles.left} rippleColor={'transparent'} 
                />}
        right={<TextInput.Icon icon={rightIcon?()=>rightIcon:undefined} 
                onPress={onPress} style={styles.right} 
                rippleColor={'transparent'}  />}
        keyboardType={keyboardType}
        returnKeyType={returnKeyType}
        defaultValue = {defaultValue}
        placeholder={placeholder} 
        placeholderTextColor={COLORS.medgray}
        secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
        maxLength={maxLength}
        testID={testID}
      />
      } />
      <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name={name}  render={({ message }) =>
            <Error message={message} />} />
            </View>
    )
}
```

here where I use thee reusable input

signup.tsx

```
const { handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }, control,setValue,getValues,reset } = useForm<FormProps>({
      resolver: yupResolver<FormProps>(registerSchema) ,
      mode: "onChange",
      defaultValues: {fullName:'', 
      Email :'',
      passWordU:'',
      city :'',
      Addressu:'',
      phone:'',
    }
  });

return(
...
           <Input   
               control={control}
                name={'Email'}
                errors={errors}
                value={value}
                 ...
                
              />

)
```

and it also used in another forms like that so I need errors type to be accurate enough